# IE object expected maps API v3 onload external .js function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, onload

I have a small Google maps v3 script that works fine on all proper browsers, but when it encounters IE I get a "object expected" error no matter what event handler I use or different way of writing the attributes. Help!

The script here:

```
function include(filename)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = filename;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    head.appendChild(script)
}


include('geoxml3.js');
include('v3_epoly.js');

  var geoXml = null;
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var toggleState = 1;
    var infowindow = null;
    var marker = null;
    var Ploc = null;
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
//Voting Locations: Array element id = voting pct!
    var Vloc = new Array();
        Vloc[1] = 's';
        Vloc[2] = 's';
        Vloc[3] = 's';
        Vloc[4] = 's';


 function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();  
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new google.maps.Size(150,50) }); 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.5890, -96.308871);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }


     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel')); 
    geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        polygonOptions: {clickable: false}, 
        });
    geoXml.parse('qvote.kml');
    // exml = new EGeoXml({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true, createpolygon: createPoly});
  }

function showAddress(address) {
    var contentString = '';
    Ploc = null;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var point = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(point);
          if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: point
          });
        for (var i=0; i<geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons.length; i++) {
          if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[i].Contains(point)) {
            contentString = address+'<br>'+geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[i].name;
    //      contentString += '<br>'+point+'<br>polygon#'+i;
            Ploc = geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[i].name;
            i = 999; // Jump out of loop
          }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        if (Ploc) calcRoute(address);
        });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
}
function calcRoute(addy) {
  var start = addy;
  var end = Vloc[parseInt(Ploc)];
  var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

The page its on here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="calvoteroute.js"></script>
<title>Voter Map</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

<style type="text/css"> 
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
.bla {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad='initialize()'>

<div><img src="img/pollingbanner.png" width="663" height="126"/></div>
<div><form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false;" style="height:100%; width:100%; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; background:none;"> 
    <p>
      <label class="bla">Enter the voter's address to find location:</label> 

      <input type="text" size="40" name="address" value="3003 S. Washington, Kaufman TX 75142" class="address" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go Vote!"/>
    <br />
    Scroll below to see the current Polling locations
</form></div>
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:663px; height:600px; display: table-cell;"></div>
        <div id="directionsPanel" style="width: 200px; height: 600px; display: table-cell;"></div>    
        </div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the event with:
`google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);` and it displays fine in IE 8/9.

Answer (score 2):

A link to your map would let us tell where the problem is (even with IE's debugger).

Guessing.  IE helpfully adds an additional null object at the end of array and anonymous objects that have a "hanging comma" (a comma with nothing after it) at the end.  Like you have here:

```
geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    polygonOptions: {clickable: false},   <----------------- bad in IE...
    });
```

That may not be the problem or the only problem, but it will cause an issue in IE.